# after changing language , folder not shown when being created by command line

Tags: command-line, graphics, directory, language-support, chinese

i create a new folder or document with the terminal,like

```
mkdir test
```

By using 'ls', i make sure that the folder is created successfuly.
But it does not show in the graphical view.

So, l try to create it from the graphical view. But saddly, it show a error like this.
[the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IT9a.png).

"Error when getting information for file “/home/me/桌面”: No such file or directory"

When i firstly using the ubunto, i set the language of Chinese. When using, i want to set back to English.I have follow the instruction to set all the folder names to English names.But i do not know why the inner code does not change, so this error happened.

Futhermore, i change the language back to Chinese. The folder shows in the graphical view and i can also create in the graphical view . But i change back to English Language, this problem happened again.  :(

Any clues? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the steps you followed to change the language. From the looks of the error, you may be missing some language files, which can result in some codepage issues.

Comment: thanks for your help    :)       (0)the version of Ubuntu is : ubuntu-20.04.4-desktop-amd64    (1)the steps: i open the "Settings" and choose "Region and Language". I set the language with "English(United States)" and click the "Restart".  When the ubuntu is restared, it ask me to decide whether to change the new name in English or keep the old name in Chinese. And i chose to change the new English name.That is all.  I think some code of graphical view is not changed when i changing the language and the error happens.

Comment: As you see the error showd before, "桌面" is the desktop meaning in Chinese. But the name has changed to Desktop now.So the computer can not find the fold with Chinese name. But i donot know how to change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the state of the machine, there may be a few things you'll need to check/update. First let's confirm that you have all of the necessary language packages installed:

1. Press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and search for "Language":
   [image: Language Support]
2. The application will check to ensure all of the necessary definitions are installed:
   [image: Checking available language support]
3. If a message pops up saying that some languages are not fully installed, select "Install" and give the system a few moments.
4. Check to ensure the languages that you want to use on the machine are properly selected:
   [image: Installed Languages List]
5. If any languages are not checked, install the packages, then log out and back in to ensure everything is properly loaded.

The next item you'll want to check is the `user-dirs.dirs` file located in `~/.config`. This is probably simplest via Terminal:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Open the directory definition file:

   ```
   {editor of choice} ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice, be it `nano`, `vi`, `gedit`, or something else entirely.</sup>
2. Confirm the directory names are set to their English definitions:

   ```
   XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
   XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
   XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
   XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
   XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
   XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
   XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
   XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
   ```

   If any are still showing their Chinese definitions, be sure to update them to the correct values.
3. If the `user-dirs.dirs` file received updates, log out and back in again

This should ensure you have a properly configured desktop.

Comment: thanks a lot , the directory names are wrong which did not change with the language changing.  This is my first quention , and l am really happy to get your help, thanks again. : )